# How to make an item not iterable by pressing tab

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make specific objects on a web page NOT iterable when a user presses tab. To be more specific I have a web page with text input boxes and check boxes, if a user presses 'tab' I want the web browser to iterate through the text input boxes but skip over the check boxes.

But in a general sense which objects can the web browser 'tab' through? How is this set/controlled?

Comment: Sounds like you're removing useful functionality, but if you really want to do that, look at using the [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute

Comment: this isn´t a good practice, since the tab is used by blind users

Comment: try giving tabindex="-1" if you want to skip the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute `tabIndex = "-1"` inside your HTML element

```html
<input />
<p>This bunch of checkboxes will be skipped on Tab</p>
<input tabIndex="-1"  type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input tabIndex="-1"  type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input tabIndex="-1"  type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="Boat"> I have a boat<br>
<input />
```